# How to connect a boost::signal2::signal to a pure virtual function?

Tags: c++, qt, boost, architecture, signals

I am using `boost::signals2::signals` in a component, `UpdateComponent`.  A specific aggregate for this component is of type `Updateable`. I would like `Updateable` to be able to connect to `UpdateComponent`'s `boost::signals2::signal`.  I should note that the `Updateable`'s `slot` is `pure-virtual`.

Below is a concrete example of the code:

```
// This is the component that emits a boost::signals2::signal.
class UpdateComponent {
    public:
        UpdateComponent();
        boost::signals2::signal<void (float)> onUpdate; // boost::signals2::signal
}
```

At some point in `UpdateComponent`'s code, I perform `onUpdate(myFloat)`;  I believe this is akin to "firing" the `boost::signals2::signal` to all of its "listeners".

```
// The is the aggregate that should listen to UpdateComponent's boost::signals2::signal
class Updateable {
    public:
        Updateable();
    protected:
        virtual void onUpdate(float deltaTime) = 0; // This is the pure-virtual slot that listens to UpdateComponent.
        UpdateComponent* m_updateComponent;
}
```

In `Updateable`'s constructor, I do the following:

```
Updateable::Updateable {
    m_updateComponent = new UpdateComponent();
    m_updateComponent->onUpdate.connect(&onUpdate);
}
```

I receive the following two errors:

1. `...Updateable.cpp:8: error: ISO C++ forbids taking the address of an unqualified or parenthesized non-static member function to form a pointer to member function.  Say '&BalaurEngine::Traits::Updateable::onUpdate' [-fpermissive]`
2. `/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:225: error: no match for call to '(boost::_mfi::mf1<void, BalaurEngine::Traits::Updateable, float>) (float&)'`

I should mention I am using Qt in conjunction with boost.  However, I have added `CONFIG            += no_keywords` to my `.pro` file, so the two should be work together smoothly, as outlined on the boost website.  The reason I don't use Qt's `signals` and `slots` (which works very well) is: I do not want `Updateable` to be a `QObject`.

If someone could help me figure out why I am getting an error, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I can't give a concrete example since I don't use boost for signals and slots, but I can tell you that the problem arises because you're trying to connect to a non-static member function, which implicitly takes a pointer to an object as a parameter.  Googling indicates that using `boost::bind` is the way to do this.

Comment: Thank you, tmpearce.  As irobot said below, this is the cause of my problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The slot you are passing to `connect` must be a functor. To connect to a member function, you can use either `boost::bind` or C++11 `lambda`. For example using lambda:

```
Updateable::Updateable {
    m_updateComponent = new UpdateComponent();
    m_updateComponent->onUpdate.connect(
        [=](float deltaTime){ onUpdate(deltaTime); });
}
```

or using `bind`:

```
Updateable::Updateable {
    m_updateComponent = new UpdateComponent();
    m_updateComponent->onUpdate.connect(
        boost::bind(&Updateable::onUpdate, this, _1));
}
```

Comment: Thank you, irobot.  I was unaware of this.

Comment: Well, it would have been nice if it worked the way you though it works!

Comment: Yes it would! I've been spoiled by Qt's SIGNALS and SLOTS macros (similar syntax), which, I admit, makes life much more enjoyable.  However, using Qt's SIGNALS and SLOTS means you must inherit from QObject, which bloats a given class.  Thanks again for the help, irobot.